# How to create dropmenu?

Tags: css

I want to create dropmenu, but when I click headline main menu, drop menu is inline. I don,t know where is problem. I will gratefull if someone help me.

```
nav{
    display:flex;
    background-color:black;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    font-size:15px;
    justify-content:center;
}

nav ul{
    display:flex;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    margin:20px;
}

nav ul li ul li{
    display:none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add display: block on your nested ul tag.

Is this what you wanted ? :)

```css
nav{
    display:flex;
    background-color:black;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    font-size:15px;
    height: 50px;
    justify-content:center;
}

nav ul{
    display:flex;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    margin:20px;
}

nav ul li ul {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li{
    display:none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li{
    display:block;
    color : white ;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a>Menu 1</a>
   <ul>
    <li>Hi</li>
    <li>Yo</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a>Menu 2</a>
   <ul>
    <li>Hi</li>
    <li>Yo</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: sorry i did not understand your comment

Comment: can you be more specific on what you want exactly ? ^^

Comment: when i click main headline in menu all background nav is rolling, and should only menu which i click